# What's the most idiomatic long table eqivalent of subtracting two data.frame columns?

Tags: r, dplyr

In a `wide` table, dividing columns is easy:

```
t=read.table(header=TRUE,text=
    " gene time  Green   Red
      G1   t0    10      4
      G1   t1    15      6
      G2   t0    25      3
      G2   t1    32      4")
t$ratio = t$Green/t$Red

##   gene time Green Red    ratio
## 1   G1   t0    10   4 2.500000
## 2   G1   t1    15   6 2.500000
## 3   G2   t0    25   3 8.333333
## 4   G2   t1    32   4 8.000000
```

I want to archive the same in a `long` table.
That is, applying a function on two or more values that match in one factor and have pairwise different levels of another factor while being able to reference each value in the computation by its distinctive factor

The only solution I found so far is converting the table to the `wide` format and then proceeding as above.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
t = read.table(text=
               " gene  ex  dye  time 
                 G1    4   R    t0
                 G2    3   R    t0
                 G1    10  G    t0
                 G2    25  G    t0
                 G1    6   R    t1
                 G2    4   R    t1
                 G1    15  G    t1
                 G2    32  G    t1
             ",header=TRUE)

spread(t,dye,ex) %>% 
    mutate(dye.ratio = G/R) %>%
    select(-G,-R) 

##   gene time dye.ratio
## 1   G1   t0  2.500000
## 2   G1   t1  2.500000
## 3   G2   t0  8.333333
## 4   G2   t1  8.000000
```

Is there a more idiomatic way of performing this quite basic task which perhaps needs even less than three statements?

Comment: @akrun I think hes is looking for `setDT(df)[, ex[dye=='G']/ex[dye=='R'], keyby = .(gene, time)]` or similarly `df %>% group_by(gene, time) %>% summarise(dye.ratio =  ex[dye=='G']/ex[dye=='R'])` with `dplyr`

Comment: @akrun, no, he wanted to mimic the result he achieved using `tidyr`

Comment: @DavidArenburg Yes, you are right. I didn't read it carefully.  You could post the solutions

Comment: @akrun I don't think it's any cleaner than the OPs solution really. Not sure what he is looking for

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. @DavidArenburg 's solution is was what I was looking for. I always thought dplyr and tidyr were complements to each other so I didn't know my choice of packages could cause confusion among you ;-)

Comment: I think your solution is fine too so I don't think mine and akruns solution are any better. It's a matter of taste I guess.